# Understanding bases for eigenspaces of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}6&3&-8\\0&-2&0\\1&0&-3\end{bmatrix}
I want to find the characteristic equation, the eigenvalues, and the bases for the eigenspaces.

I get the characteristic equation to: $\lambda^3 - \lambda^2 - 16\lambda -20$
and the eigenvalues to $λ=-2 λ=-2 \lambda=5$.

Now as I understand i need to find a eigenvector that fulfills $( − )x = 0$ where $x$ is a nonzero vector.

To do this i take the eigenvalues and input them into the following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}-6&-3&8\\0&+2&0\\-1&0&+3\end{bmatrix}

So now for example I found out that one of the eigenvalues is $ = -2$ so i get the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}-8&3&-8\\0&0&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

From here I don't follow what is the correct way to solve this, when i check on sites like quizlet how they further solved this they simply say that they multiply that matrix with:
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}
Then it says as follow

**from where we get the general solution $x_1=t, x_2=0, x_3=t$ which we re write as:**

\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\\t\end{bmatrix}
**taking $t=0$ and $s=1$ a basis for this eigenspace is**
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}

How did they get the "general solution" and what decides what values they choose for $t$ and $s$? And what is s? I have tried multiple questions of the same kind and don't grasp how to find the base for the eigenspace. Am I suppose to input the eigenvalues that I find into the matrix and then do Gaussian elimination on that matrix to somehow find the general solution. And what happens if when I input my eigenvalue and the matrix becomes a zero matrix?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why are you asking us what $s$ is? You should ask it to whoever wrote about it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your comment, since I can't follow how they solved this I thought that the s was crucial for solving the exercise. Is the s not supposed to be there? I copied over the exact words they used for solving the bases

Comment: I have no idea about what that $s$ might be. If you want me to provide an answer to the question of how to determine a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2$, I can do that.

Comment: You want the matrix $\lambda I-A$, but that's not what you've written. On the diagonal you have written $\lambda I-A$, but everywhere else you just have $A$. Anyway, you have never been taught how to solve a system of three equations in three unknowns? or, to put it another way, how to find the nullspace of a matrix? Usually, that's done long before you study eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Alright then it might have been a typo on their behalf, yes i would very much like that if you have the possibility

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your comment. You are very much correct I will edit this. Yes I have but I dont understand what the 3 equations are suppose to be, would the correct way be to use Gaussian elimination and then solve the equation system?

Comment: You corrected the 2nd displayed matrix, but you didn't carry the correction through to the 3rd displayed matrix.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}-8&3&-8\\0&0&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Then the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2$ are the non-zero vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that$$\begin{bmatrix}-8&3&-8\\0&0&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$This is the same thing as asserting that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-8x_1+3x_2+8x_3=0\\x_1+x_3=0,\end{array}\right.$$which is equivalent to $x_3=-x_1$ and $x_2=0$. So, the eigenvectors that you are interested in are those of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\0\\-x_1\end{bmatrix}=x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$and so a basis of the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-2$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and giving a detailed answer. Do we ever do Gaussian elimination to find x1,x2 and x3 or do we always try to find a common answer for x1 like you did in your answer?

Comment: We do Gaussian elimination whenever we want to do it. In this case, I did not want to do it. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: $x_3=-x_1$ seems wrong for $x_1-x_3=0$...I guess this is probably related to the error in calculating $-2I - A$ in the OP.

Comment: @forsb Gaussian elimination is what you will usually do. Occasionally you can take shortcuts; for example in the 2x2 case, as long as the eigenvalue is correct, you don't need to do Gaussian elimination because all it's going to do is zero out one of the rows anyway. But here you kinda do need to do it, at least "in your head", to get to the observation that $x_2=0,x_1=x_3$.

Comment: @Ian It was a typo. I've edited my answer.